# Page Not Found for questions deleted via moderation needs updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, deleted-questions

For <10k users, when you click on a deleted question instead of seeing the question, you are presented with a page saying "Page Not Found" with a few links to similar questions and also information on who deleted it (self deletion or moderation deletion). This works as it should, but the layout of the pages needs updating for moderation deleted questions as the content overlaps.

[image]

[image]

As you can see on the main site it is not too much of an issue. All the content is still readable and realigning the content just makes it look the same as the other page, but it isn't necessary.

---

However, if we look at the Meta versions of the same pages, it's just awful and unreadable to the point that persuaded me to tag this with being a bug. Especially the part circled in blue as it can't be read unless you zoom in a bit (or the old fashioned way of moving your face closer to the screen) due to the text overlapping the image.

[image]

[image]

Yes, this will likely be a quick fix (but will still be 6-8 weeks), but why are the two pages laid out differently in the first place?

**Links to try it out for yourselves:**

1. [Main Site Author Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326668/store-msmq-message-to-sql-table)
2. [Main Site Moderation Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099693/hi-all-since-i-am-new-to-phython-i-would-like-you-to-help-me-with-combining-thr)
3. [Meta Author Delete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365863/max-ratio-of-negative-positive-votes)
4. [Meta Moderation Delete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371224/i-would-like-to-move-unity3d-related-posts-to-a-separate-community)

Comment: You give the why yourself: it's a bug. A simple CSS problem, most likely. It happens especially since the UI is under continuous development, styling fixing are generally done quite rapidly once the person who goofed up feels the burning heat of shame ;)

Comment: May we have 2 links so we can aprreciate it ourself ? for those who don't know how to find a deleted question

Comment: @Gimby yes of course it will be a simple problem, just that someone needs to report it so they know they goofed up :)

Comment: @DragandDrop added some links (I find deleted questions because I flag a lot and access them via my flag history)

Comment: Hm, the problem does not reproduce on my system (Chrome, MacOS). Maybe its browser or even browser version specific too.

Comment: @Gimby same thing here, it's fine on Chrome and FF (windows)

Comment: @Gimby never thought of it being browser specific, just tried IE, Edge and Chrome, layout seems to be fine for Crome and Edge, behaviour seen in the question is from IE

Comment: I couldn't repro on Chrome, Edge or IE (Win10)

Comment: If it's only on IE then it's not  a bug, it's a feature to discourage people using IE;)

Comment: I can reproduce (IE11 on Windows 8.1)

Comment: I can reproduce this on IE11 on windows 7, but not on FF or Chrome.

Comment: When are we going to stop supporting IE?

Comment: @TinyGiant when friend WhatsThePoint stops using it!

Comment: @Gimby you'll have to drag me away kicking and screaming

Comment: @WhatsThePoint *using* IE makes *me* want to scream...

Comment: @JaredSmith using IE is basically an AD blocker as most ads nowadays aren't compliable with IE :P

Comment: @TemaniAfif even if you don't care about people who are using it by choice because you think they're a bit crazy, show some sympathy for those working in crappy corporate environments that only let them use IE because changing a policy - from circa 2000 when mandating IE6 instead of NS4.7 wasn't insane - is bureaucratically impossible.

Comment: Can not reproduce. Latest FF Win 10. Works bloody fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been working on the responsive layout and it looks like the issue has fixed itself!  I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE 11.

Comment: I just tested in IE11 with the links I provided in the question and they all seemed to behave as normal (no overlapping text) I also opened them all up in Chrome and everything still seems to be ok

Answer (score 3):

This thoroughly [nerd-sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) me. This appears to be a [rendering bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/134) in IE11 with `flex-basis: auto` (which might be related to [text wrapping](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/170)).  If you inspect the `img`, you'll notice that it is overflowing its parent in IE11 (and not in other browsers).  Setting `.g-col` to `flex: 1 1 0%` instead of `flex: 1 auto` as recommended in the linked github issue seems to resolve it in IE, but *might* cause problems in other browsers.  Not sure if SO wants to hack their beautiful new CSS or if they will [status-decline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-decline) this.

If you wanted to add a userstyle in the meantime,

```
.g-col {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

should fix it for you.

## Here's some screenshots of what is going on:

## Parent div too small with default `flex` value

[image: g-col flex issue]

## `img` overflowing parent div with default `flex` value

[image: img flex issue]

## Parent div working properly with `flex: 1 1 0%`

[image: flex issue fixed]

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this was indeed fixed by a recent refactor of our error page layout. Cool!